# Detect tap on green tag in call kit

Tags: swift, swiftui, callkit, pushkit, uiscenedelegate

We are using call kit to receive calls for our app. When call is received on call kit green tag appears on left top as shown in the image attached. When user taps on green tag application is resumed from background.

We are unable to detect the app activation due to tap on call kit green tag. We are using SceneDelegate as project is in swift UI.

We have tried following functions but they are called every time when application return from background. We also explored CXProviderDelegate.

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)
```

[image]